# Restore GRUB after Windows installation (Arch Linux)

Tags: linux, windows, windows-7, grub, boot

After installing Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on a machine running Arch Linux the MBR became rewritten (I do not think GRUB has been uninstalled). Arch is now unbootable except if I use the live-CD to boot, and then choose from the local drives.

The disk where Win7 was installed is hd0 and the one where Arch is hd1.

Is there a way to restore GRUB and make the system dual-booting? It would be best if it could be done from within the Arch environment (after all I have found the workaround with the live-CD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some digging, I found what I was looking for, so here is what worked for me.

Arch has always been on hd1 and windows on hd0. Grub was never uninstalled from hd1 where he was initially placed during the Arch installation. It was "just" the boot sector that got removed by the Win7 installation (if I am mistaken you are welcome to correct me).

What I did was run grub in the terminal so that I get its CLI. This is what I typed afterwards:

```
    find /boot/grub/stage1
    root (hd1,1)
    setup (hd0)
```

The last line was counterintuitive (at least for me) because I expected it to be "hd1" in order to correspond with where the Arch installation was.

Answer (score 1):

Try runing "grub-install" from your arch enviroment. If you didn't have windows before, edit the grub configuration and add windows to your config.